# Skip False while removing 0 in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to remove all the zeroes in my list which contains integers, booleans and string type data.
I am aware that False is evaluated as 0 in python.
But is there a way to skip False while removing 0 from my list?

```
while 0 in li :
           li.remove(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, since, from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

> `list.remove(x)`
>
> Remove the first item from the list whose value is ***equal*** to `x`. It raises a `ValueError` if there is no such item.

And:

```
>>> 0 == False
True
>>> 1 == True
True
```

Using `list.remove` with `0` will remove `False` as well (and vice-versa), and with `1` will remove `True` as well (and vice-versa), so, for now it's better to use a list comprehension for this:

```
li = [i for i in li if type(i) != int or i]
```

You can also use the built-in function `filter`:

```
li = list(filter(lambda i : type(i) != int or i, li))
```

Comment: The problem arises when I try to remove the 0 in my list. It removes False as well

Comment: @Newbiew9232 This is apparently a problem with `list.remove`, because it uses equality, where `0 == False` and `1 == True`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use check type and 0 like below

```py
ls = [True, False, 0, 3, 4, "abc", "xyx", 0, "o"]

[item for item in ls if (type(item)!=int) or (item!=0)]
```